# Unable to get basic query in MySQL to work when comparing strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having difficulty retrieving basic data in a query.

I have a relation with three columns, an `id` which is an `INT` and `PRIMARY KEY` and I have two more columns that are `VARCHAR(30)` called `fname` and `lname`.

I cannot get my basic query to work when asking for people by name. I can get my query to work when asking by id.

for example:

```
select * from customers where cid = 2; -- Does work :)
```

and

```
select * from customers where fname = 'Bob'; -- Does not work  :(
```

I've also tried many variations with different quotation makes like the double quote and the key above the tab key. And yes, there is a record with the name Bob

Can anyone help me out with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the two queries you have shown are all valid.

Comment: That query will work if there is someone with fname `Bob`. Are you sure that `Bob` is exactly what the field contains?  Is this query the exact one you have that is not working?

Comment: Are you sure that there are no trailing spaces after/before the entered value? Can you paste the result of SELECT CONCAT('|',fname,'|') from customers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reasonable possibility that the field doesn't contain the word 'Bob' without whitespace (spaces, tabs, carriage returns, etc) or perhaps it was put in the 'lname' field accidentally.  Try:

```
select * from customers where fname like 'Bob%' or lname like 'Bob%';
```

and check any results for extra whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I used a php script to create the simulated database. What I did was create a text file with a bunch of names and each name was on a new line. So as it turns out, there is a hidden carriage return character hiding there... Thanks dan1111

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE fname='Bob\n';
```

Thanks all!